# How to redirect the site according to browser language?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having 2 site in different language on same domain,

Suppose, 2 language A and B, which run like below
A site run from "http://site.com" (default site).
and 
B site run from "http://sit.com/b/"

if user browse the "http://site.com" then if browser language is A then its open the default site and if browser language is set as "B" then it should open site like "http://sit.com/b/". and if browser having any other language then in all cases it open only default site,

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Whatever solution you end up with, make sure that there's an escape valve of some kind (e.g. allow the user to perform an action on the `/b/` site, such that a cookie is set, such that the redirection doesn't occur). Sometimes, the user really, really, may want to access the default site, despite their browser language being `B`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is correct.  It is infuriating to go to a news site and have it constantly ask me if I want the "International Edition" because I am accessing it from outside the US.  *No, I want the damn US edition - same thing I do every day*.

Comment: This may be of help for you http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/localization/culture.aspx#autoculture

Comment: Also, if its just about language, maybe you should consider putting the strings of your web page into resource files, and have different resource files for different languages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246(v=vs.100).aspx additionally, you can make the language choosable by setting the language through Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture...

Answer (score 0):

You can detect browser language by following code.

```
HttpRequest Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;       

     if (Request.UserLanguages == null)
            return;

    string Lang = Request.UserLanguages[0];
```

Now you have the browser language on behalf of that you can redirect to particular site.

```
if(lang=="A")
Response.Redirect("A site")
else
Respose.Redirect("B site");
```

Comment: i can understand this, but where i have to write this code, if i write this in Global.asax file then its not working Can you suggest the correct location?

Comment: you can write this code on your default website's default page in PageLoad() method.  Every time request will come on your default page from there you can redirect.

Comment: It may happen you don’t know what page will the user enter your site -a blog that may be accessed through organic search-. How can you redirect him to the proper language specific site?